# Are there Windows alternatives to Wireless Security auditor?

Tags: wireless-networking

I am aware that there are plenty of Linux based alternatives however we require a Windows application. Are there any alternatives to Wireless Security auditor?

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear as to what features you actually need?

Comment: Iszi - I am not looking for specific features per se however an application that allows me to audit wireless networks on Windows

Comment: What are you trying to audit about them?

Comment: "Audit Wireless Networks" can cover a wide range of requirements, or lack thereof.  What radio spectra are you auditing (2.4 GHz, 5 GHz, or both)?  Do you need something that does packet captures as well as device hunting?  Are you interested in only seeing Access Points, or do you need something to help hunt down client or ad-hoc devices as well?

Comment: @Iszi - I am auditing from radio spectrums and yes I do need something that does packet captures as well as device hunting. I am interested in access points, clients and ad-hoc devices. I also intend to use the tool to simulate someone attempting to access the wireless network

Comment: Sounds like you want BackTrack, and a *lot* of lessons in Linux and the use of hacking tools.  If you get a USB Wi-Fi adapter, you can run BackTrack on top of Windows in a VM.